Ethernet cable testing
I'm working on designing a device to identify ethernet cables after they have been installed.  I've designed a circuit that will send a DC high signal via one wire and then returned over the remaining wires.  The remote device will have the wires connected differently (with a DIP switch) to ID each cable.  I've been reading up on RJ45 magnetics in RJ45 connectors and, if I understand it correctly, this will prevent a DC signal from being transmitted.  Is that correct?  If so, it looks like I will need to redesign it to send a pulsed signal.

Yes.  I was going to test them after they were installed in a wall jack and patch panel which I'd assume would both have magnetics.   Any idea what minimum signal frequency should work?

You should be able to find RJ45 connectors both with and without magnetics. Or RJ45 connectors with circuitry to split DC and signals.

I don't think there should be magnetics in a wall jack. Routers, switches, and computers, yes. Wall jacks no. If you just want to test the wall jacks, there is something called a fox and hound. It used to be used for telephone wiring, and used the telephone plugs, but there is probably a version for RJ45.

Not suggesting this is a good device, but it may serve your purpose. https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Multifunction-Maintenance-Telephone-Earphones/dp/B09N3CB4BX/ref=asc_df_B09N3CB4BX/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=633056471951&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3083711522344476621&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001667&hvtargid=pla-1917380819485&mcid=b97e32ef2e1a386f8920ccf32359e289&gclid=Cj0KCQjwn7mwBhCiARIsAGoxjaLdwoMZhmuEwWxnWSgDh2jfSic5TUJXn4Sqd6QDt9JjC1e0NDp3kx0aAlbaEALw_wcB&th=1

Ok thanks.  I'll take a look at that.  I may just wire up my existing design and just see if it works with the wall jacks and patch panel

you can buy such a device ... handheld device with multiple remote fobs for identifying cables

wall jacks and patch panels do not have magnetics

I'm not wanting to purchase but instead design myself for educational purposes

Please understand that accidentally sending voltage or current to an actual device plugged on the cabling instead of your ID resistor may damage the device magnetics. It depends on how much voltage/current you allow, but the transformers are not intended to be fed with DC.

Also, you talk about identifying, and then about testing. In theory you can try to identify the cable based on measuring your ID resistance. But just having an ID resistor will not test for any other problems. Even if all 8 wires test at DC to go to correct pins, Ethernet will not work well if the wire pairs are paired incorrectly.

My current design limits voltage to 5v and 100uA.  I would think most transformers would be able to handle that.

For Ethernet, magnetics are used only in devices, never in cables or wall jacks (at least in standard installations).
As for PCB-mount connectors that you might use in your project, some have built-in magnetics but many, including lower-priced ones, do not and would be suitable for your purpose.

PoE injectors. They have transformers for data, and passive injectors forcibly apply power even without requesting. Any weird testing must be made on pure cables only, or some device plugged in may damage.
